# Task Manager's Force Close Delete my app's preferences but why?

Tags: android

Im building my first android game, my problem is:

When I exit from the app with my phone's "back\exit" button, my app is closing and all the information I need is nicely saved to a preference file:

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() 
 {

 super.onPause();

 // My pref file
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

 // Put the values to the pref file
 editor.putInt("CsereHolTart", CsereHolTart);
 editor.putInt("melyikAct", melyikAct);
 editor.putInt("Silver", Silver);
 editor.putInt("Strength", Strength);
 editor.putInt("Intelligence", Intelligence);
 editor.putInt("Dexterity", Dexterity);
 editor.putInt("Speed", Speed);
 editor.putInt("Vitality", Vitality);
 editor.putInt("Morale", Morale);
 editor.putInt("cHp", cHp);
 editor.putInt("cMp", cMp);

 editor.putInt("isGame", 1);



 // Commit to storage
 editor.commit();


  }
```

See? I simply use the onPause() method to put all the things I need to a preference file actually to this:

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
```

When I open the app, all the saved data is well read, and my app continues from the right pont with the valid values I saved then loaded.

THIS IS GOOD, BUT:

When I close my applicaton with my phone's task manager, so i manually do a "force close", it seems onPause() is just not running, or something else I dont know. So the matter is when I close my app with task manager, all the loadings are fails, it seems all the saved data is deleted. Becuse every preference is loaded to default in that way.

Can anybody tell me what should I do to solve this task manager's force close problem?
I want to save and load everytime the user exit from the app or opens the app.

Comment: As you say, it shouldn't matter about onPause() not being called so long as the preferences were saved previously. I can only guess that you are deleting this saved data somewhere along the line. Can you post the code you use to load the shared preferences?

Comment: When I exit via my phone's exit button, all things all saved, and well loaded. But when I use the task manager, no loadings happen.
I just dont get it... whats the difference between both close?

This is my load, it is simple:
`
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, 0);

        isGame=preferences.getInt("isGame", 0);
                
        
        if(isGame==1)
        { 
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(KezdoKepernyo.this, ThamirMain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        }`

Comment: This is my load, it is simple:

  `SharedPreferences preferences =` `getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, 0);`

        `isGame=preferences.getInt("isGame", 0);`
                
        
        `if(isGame==1)`
        `{` 
        `Intent intent = new Intent();`
        `intent.setClass(KezdoKepernyo.this, ThamirMain.class);`
        `startActivity(intent);`
        `finish();`
        `}`

Comment: My suspicion is that you are not really saving the preferences in onPause. The state of your app is being maintained and it coincidentally works fine. To test this, try using your app, changing the preferences, then hitting home or back. Then reboot your phone. If the preferences did not persist, then its likely that you either do not load them or do not save them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I close my applicaton with my phone's task manager, so i manually do a "force close", it seems onPause() is just not running

If you are in the foreground and kill the process via some sort of task manager, `onPause()` will not be called. `onPause()` is only called when some other activity takes over the foreground.

Comment: If onPause() is not called on force close, where the hell should I save all my data? I need a way that is working on force closes.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi: "where the hell should I save all my data?" -- IMHO, few users will force close your application while it is in the foreground. For starters, few users have a device where that is even possible.

Comment: I really need a way to solve this because my game is an RPG, so the player should be able to continue his or her journey. I must get in mind that some users will force close my app, so is there a method, like onPause() that will run if someone force closes the app?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi: "I must get in mind that some users will force close my app" -- It is *physically impossible* for most of your users to force-close your app while it is in the foreground. "is there a method, like onPause() that will run if someone force closes the app?" -- no. If your app is not in the foreground, it will have been called with `onPause()`. If your users are idiots and force-close your foreground app, they deserve whatever data loss they get.

Comment: Thank you, but I must say many users force closes their apps in the foreground. I will find a way, maybe using the internal storage and saving in run time.